# Random number generator with strings

Tags: c#

I have some code that sends a number that is pre-calculated to an Arduino.
instead of a pre-calculated number, I want a random number between a range of number, for example between the numbers 1 to 20, the random number is 18,
after the random number is found put it in a string so I can work with it.

I've tried many things on stack overflow but things are too complicated and I work with C#.
the code below is what I have right now,
I would prefer that it will send that random number to the Arduino

```
namespace MyLaserTurret
{

   public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Stopwatch watch { get; set; }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            port.Open();
        }

        private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            writeToPort(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
        }

        public void writeToPort(Point coordinates)
        {
            if (watch.ElapsedMilliseconds > 15)
            {
                watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

                port.Write(String.Format("X{0}Y{1}",
                (coordinates.X / (Size.Width / 180)),
                (coordinates.Y / (Size.Height / 180))));
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Size.Width / 180` - *integer division* (will be `0` if `Size.Width < 180`) - you, probably, mean `Size.Width / 180.0` - *floating point* value

Comment: A simple "Generate random number c#" search would have given you the answer

Answer (score 2):

To create a random number as a string you use this code

```
    private Random random = new Random();  

    public string RandomNumber(int min, int max)
    {
        return random.Next(min, max).ToString();
    }
```

Please note that it is probably best practice to declare a "Random random = new Random();" as a class property because when a Random is created too closely together they will just keep having the same value

Comment: `private static Random random = new Random();`, but it's not thread safe

Comment: `public string RandomNumber(int min, int max) => random.Next(min, max).ToString();` to put it short

Comment: @RemcoKieu Wherever the pre-generated number is being used